# Time travel and time freezing in Elixir

Tags: mocking, erlang, elixir

When writing integration tests that depend on the current date/time, it is very handy to be able to `freeze` or `travel` to specific moment (like e.g. [timecop](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop) for ruby)

Is there a way to achieve something similar in Elixir/Erlang?

I tried mocking Erlang built-ins `:os.timestamp`, `:erlang.universaltime` using `meck` library, however it fails with `:cannot_mock_builtin`.

In principle I could implement my own utility library than would enable easy mocking of current time and then use it everywhere instead of built-in methods; however, some libraries use built-ins, so this is not a viable option (e.g `Ecto.Model.Timestamps`, generating `inserted_at` and `updated_at` values)

Comment: Have you checked the recent changelog for Erlang 18? It has a TImeWarp feature and ferd has written about it in learnyousomeerlang. [Erlang time warp documentation](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/time_correction.html) and [ferd writings on the subject](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/time). No sure though they answer your question...

Comment: @Olinasc The time warp feature is only related to reacting to changing system time and clocks in general, it does not allow you to change the time for tests only.

Answer (score 8):

#### Elixir

I would suggest you implement this via dependency injection. For example (using the new time API in Erlang 18):

```
defmodule Thing do
  def do_stuff(data), do: do_stuff(data, &:erlang.system_time/0)
  def do_stuff(data, time), do: {data, time.()}
end
```

In your tests, you can easily replace the time code:

```
defmodule ThingTest do
  use ExUnit.Case

  test "the time" do
    assert do_stuff("data", fn -> 123 end) == {"data", 123}
  end
end
```

#### Erlang

Here's the corresponding way to do this in Erlang:

```
-module(thing).
-export([do_stuff/1, do_stuff/2]).

do_stuff(Data) -> do_stuff(Data, fun erlang:system_time/0).

do_stuff(Data, Time) -> {Data, Time()}.
```

And the test:

```
-module(thing_tests).
-include_lib("eunit/include/eunit.hrl").

do_stuff_test() ->
    ?assertEqual({"data", 123}, do_stuff("data", fun() -> 123 end).
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However I am not sure how this approach would work in context of integration test, where _external_ libraries use `erlang:system_time` (e.g. `Ecto` for automatically setting timestamps on inserted/updated rows)...

Comment: Yes, there you have no luck. There is no way to solve that problem, unless those libraries enable a way to parameterize the time. I guess the only option you have there is to run the system in a virtual machine and modify the time outside of Erlang.

Comment: Thank you for the info - I was assuming this might be the case... I will keep question open for a while to see if someone comes up with alternative solution...

Comment: @jesenko, Well, in any case you could just fake time for the whole beam like this http://archive09.linux.com/feature/147801

Comment: For integration tests you could create a gen server with the state that you want in the tests, this article shows how to do it for an API. http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2015/10/mocks-and-explicit-contracts/

Comment: Has this been fixed/added.  I'm wanting to test that something doesn't save twice in the same minute, but I cannot check that it will save if the minute changes.